# Incorrect data displayed in Arduino to Android data transfer via USB

Tags: java, android, arduino

I'm trying to send data in the form of numbers fron my Arduino UNO R3 to my Nexus 7 tablet via USB host mode. Upon clicking a button, CheckStatus() function is called in the MainActivity java file:

```
public void CheckStatus(View v)
{
    handler = new Handler();    //allocate memory for handler
    MyThread2 checkthread = new MyThread2();
    checkthread.start();

    synchronized (this)
    {
        if (usbDeviceConnection != null)
        {
            byte[] message = new byte[1];
            message[0] = (byte) (101);  //Sening any no. to Arduino, so that it responds.

            usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut, message, message.length, 0);

        }
    }

}

class MyThread2 extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        byte x;
        String string=null;
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);

        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
        while (true)
        {
            request.queue(buffer, 1);
            if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request)
            {
                try
                {
                    x = buffer.get(0);
                    string = Byte.toString(x);
                    handler.post(new newthread(string));

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else break;
        }

    }

}

class newthread implements Runnable
{
    String str;
    public newthread(String STR)
    {
        str=STR;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        tv2.setText(str);           
    }
}
```

And this is the Arduino part:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available())
  Serial.write(7);  //Sending no. 7...
}
```

The problem here is, that whatever number I try to send from the Arduino side(be it 7 or anything,) the number 0 gets displayed instead. I think this could be a problem with data type. Can I get a hint as to where I may be going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the USB serial protocol doesn't have headers or something in the transfers? Did you initialize the USB serial chip for the correct baud rate and other settings? Are you sure there isn't a library that abstracts all this so you can just get a serial port object rather than dealing with low level USB transfers directly?

Comment: Well...I'm actually new to this. I saw an example and tried to learn by doing the same. I don't know if there is some library which would make it easier.

Comment: For general USB information in Android check [the developer guide topic on USB](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html). I believe what you need is the USB Host mode, so first check [if your Android device supports USB Host](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support). Then try to find an example for Arduino in particular. [This tutorial](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/) looks good.